# How to Add custom authorization in swagger UI?

Tags: javascript, authorization, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

In one of my Rest API call I need to add header "Authorization: partner_id  : timestamp signature"

where company name is static string it can be hardcoded where as 
partner_id is part of query parameter user inputs it and 
signature is calculated as sha256(secret,password).digest.encode('base64')

How and where can I implement this authorization as right now as I see there is only api_key, and basic authorization allowed in swagger-ui.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can easily create your own signing techniques.  From the [swagger-js](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-js#custom-request-signing) README:

```
var CustomRequestSigner = function(name) {
  this.name = name;
};

CustomRequestSigner.prototype.apply = function(obj, authorizations) {
  // do something real instead of this...
  var hashFunction = this._btoa;
  var hash = hashFunction(obj.url);

  obj.headers["signature"] = hash;
  return true;
};
```

and add it to swagger like such:

```
client.clientAuthorizations
    .add("custom", new CustomRequestSigner("custom","special-key","query"));
```

Then any operation tagged with the security requirement `custom` will have this applied.

Comment: what do you do if client.clientAuthorizations is undefined? i am getting it as undefined

Comment: I'm unclear about where all this goes?